# Merging Two Tables from Two Databases in dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Dearest,

I am almost there, but I cannot go the extra mile.
I need to do something simple: bind_row two tables from two databases. Please have a look at this simple reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI) # main DB interface
library(dbplyr) # dplyr back-end for DBs
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql
library(RSQLite)


##create the databases

df1 <- tibble(x=1:20,y=rep(c("a", "b"), 10))


df2 <- tibble(x=101:120,y=rep(c("d", "e"), 10))


con1 <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db1.sqlite")


dbWriteTable(con1,"mydata",df1, overwrite=T)

dbDisconnect(con1) # closes our DB connection



con2 <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db2.sqlite")


dbWriteTable(con2,"mydata",df2, overwrite=T)

dbDisconnect(con2) # closes our DB connection

#### Now read the databases and use union_all to bind the rows of their table

con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db1.sqlite")




db1 <- tbl(con, "mydata")

db1
#> # Source:   table<mydata> [?? x 2]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.33.0 [/tmp/RtmpIk3vcV/reprex23781b78632e/db1.sqlite]
#>        x y    
#>    <int> <chr>
#>  1     1 a    
#>  2     2 b    
#>  3     3 a    
#>  4     4 b    
#>  5     5 a    
#>  6     6 b    
#>  7     7 a    
#>  8     8 b    
#>  9     9 a    
#> 10    10 b    
#> # … with more rows


con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db2.sqlite")




db2 <- tbl(con,"mydata")


db2
#> # Source:   table<mydata> [?? x 2]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.33.0 [/tmp/RtmpIk3vcV/reprex23781b78632e/db2.sqlite]
#>        x y    
#>    <int> <chr>
#>  1   101 d    
#>  2   102 e    
#>  3   103 d    
#>  4   104 e    
#>  5   105 d    
#>  6   106 e    
#>  7   107 d    
#>  8   108 e    
#>  9   109 d    
#> 10   110 e    
#> # … with more rows

db12 <- union_all(db1, db2)
#> Error: `x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It fails because (at least I think) I should use the same connection object for both db1 and db2, see

https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/219

But I cannot get it done right. The solution must be a one-liner and any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities to try;

**1** Set `copy = TRUE` in the `union_all` command:

```
db12 <- union_all(db1, db2, copy = TRUE)
```

As per the warning this is likely to be slow, because it requires data to be copied between the two databases.

**2** Use `in_schema` to use the same connection for both:

```
con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db1.sqlite")
db1 <- tbl(con, in_schema("db1.sqlite","mydata"))
db2 <- tbl(con,in_schema("db2.sqlite","mydata"))
db12 <- union_all(db1, db2)
```

Depending on your database setup, this may not always work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but suggestion 2 does not appear to work in this case with my databases.  I get this message "Error: no such table: db1.sqlite.mydata". Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: This is not a dbplyr issue. It depends on how your databases are setup. It works in my context where (1) I can write native SQL queries that touch multiple databases at once and (2) I connect R to the database using ODBC.

Comment: Can you post for.instance how you address the second case.with odbc for the connection?

Comment: `db_connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = connection_string)`. Your `connection_string` depends on your database and the ODBC drivers you have installed. I get these details from the admin.